# keep checkbox disabled and unchecked if any other two checkboxes are checked

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to keep `#b0` disabled and unchecked if `#b1` and/or `#b2` is/are checked. The snippet below re-enables `#b0` if uncheck `#b1` or `#b2`

```
let boxes = $('#b1, #b2');
boxes.click(function() {
    if (boxes.filter(':checked').length > 0) {
        $("#b0").prop("disabled", this.checked).prop({"checked": false}, this.checked);
    } 
})

<label for="b0">1</label>
<input id="b0" name="name0" type="checkbox">

<label for="b1">2</label>    
<input id="b1" name="name1" type="checkbox">

<label for="b2">3</label>
<input id="b2" name="name2" type="checkbox">
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2heo1s4t/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the checkbox in an `else` block, like this:

```js
let used_for_contact = $('#b1, #b2');
used_for_contact.click(function() {
  if (used_for_contact.filter(':checked').length > 0) {
    $("#b0").prop("disabled", true).prop("checked", false);
  } else {
    $("#b0").prop("disabled", false);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="b0" name="info_for_contact" type="checkbox">
<label for="b0">1</label>

<input id="b1" name="info_for_contact" type="checkbox">
<label for="b1">2</label>

<input id="b2" name="info_for_contact" type="checkbox">
<label for="b2">3</label>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qo6y31c8/)